# PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active

Tags: php, mysql, module, upgrade, prestashop-1.7

I have custom payment module that I need to upgrade and while upgrade, I got an error while executing Insert query.
Error:

```
Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.
```

I can't find solution :( please guide me, If you know the solution..

I have tried other stackoverflow  link but did not help. 
this is my code:

```
 $insert = 'INSERT INTO '.$this->getTableNameSQL($tableName).' SET ';

    foreach ($tableMapping as $varName => $dbFieldName) {
        if (!isset($valueArray[$varName])) {
            if ($this->tblMapping->isAutoFill($tableName, $dbFieldName)) {
                continue;
            }

            return $this->log->put(3, "Var '$varName' not found", $valueArray);
        }

        if ($fieldsMustHaveValues && '' == trim($valueArray[$varName])) {
            return $this->log->put(3, "Var '$varName' must have a value", $valueArray);
        }

        $chkstr[$varName] = $valueArray[$varName];

        $insert .= $this->checkName($dbFieldName).' = '.$this->checkValue($valueArray[$varName]).', ';
    }
    $insert .= ' checkstr = '.$this->checkValue($this->calcCheckStr($tableName, $chkstr));

 $result = $this->prestaDb->getInstance()->execute($insert);
```

And printed insert query is:

```
INSERT INTO `ps_product_pronuxtwint_log` SET type = 'SW5mbw==', msg_type = 'U29hcFJlcXVlc3Q=', http_header = 'QXJyYXkKKAogICAgW0hvc3RdID0+IGxvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDgwCiAgICBbVXNlci1BZ2VudF0gPT4gTW96aWxsYS81LjAgKFgxMTsgVWJ1bnR1OyBMaW51eCB4ODZfNjQ7IHJ2OjYwLjApIEdlY2tvLzIwMTAwMTAxIEZpcmVmb3gvNjAuMAogICAgW0FjY2VwdF0gPT4gdGV4dC9odG1sLGFwcGxpY2F0aW9uL3hodG1sK3htbCxhcHBsaWNhdGlvbi94bWw7cT0wLjksKi8qO3E9MC44CiAgICBbQWNjZXB0LUxhbmd1YWdlXSA9PiBlbi1HQixlbjtxPTAuNQogICAgW0FjY2VwdC1FbmNvZGluZ10gPT4gZ3ppcCwgZGVmbGF0ZQogICAgW1JlZmVyZXJdID0+IGh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6ODA4MC9teXN0b3JlL2VuL0Jlc3RlbGx1bmcKICAgIFtDb250ZW50LVR5cGVdID0+IGFwcGxpY2F0aW9uL3gtd3d3LWZvcm0tdXJsZW5jb2RlZAogICAgW0NvbnRlbnQtTGVuZ3RoXSA9PiAwCiAgICBbQ29va2llXSA9PiBQcmVzdGFTaG9wLTgzMjAxNGJlODg2MmZmM2ZmMjUxZjc5OWVkY2ExMDFjPWRlZjUwMjAwY2YyMzM0N2ZlODk3MzI4NDE4NGExMjExYmFiYzliZDAwMDdmYjY4YjdlOTJiY2E1MjU0ZDIyNTViODJjMTQyMzJmMDAzNDBmYWFiNDc1MjEwNzFkOWMzMzI2NTI3NDdiMmUzZmM2MWJmYjE4N2FhMjVjODFjMmYzYTZhNGMxZjQ2NWViNmYzNjQxZDYxZDYyZThhNDlhMjVlYTU3YjZiNGMyZTlkOTBmYzRhZjI2NWViMzgxYzFkYTU3Y2FjMzE0MWU0ZGFhNjFhOWRhNjRlYTNjY2YwNTU1ZjA5ZDRhMDJhOTYxYzYzOGZhNDI3ZGZmMzdkODAzOGUwNmE2YjYwM2QxYjAzYzM0MTE0ODExZWJjOTFkNWVjMzc5Y2VjYjhlYmY0ZWQyNDQ2NWY5NWNhMjM1ZGFlZTc4ZTg3NTc3OWZmZGJkYTY1MmJkMTgzMjg1YjU5ZWI1MTJiZDM0NzJjNDcxNjQxYWQxNDllNWMzMDJhNzFjZDkyOGQxNGU4MjEzYWRjYWM4Y2I3ZTZiYjJlNzVlOGVhYWY0NGM0YzNlZTA3NzQ1MDU0NjQwZjhiYTUwZGU4ZDI1MmIxYTY3M2EwZWM5MmQ0YWZjYmIwNDIzMzg1NjE5MmZkZTYyMDk0ZWViZjY2NjY0MzZmNTE4ZWE3NTIxNDdmMmU3ZTYxNDkwODQxZTdiMDcyMmZkNDhmZWJjMWIwZTAzNTYzYzFkM2M3NzA0ZDIyMzU2MWE1OGJhYWU2OTk4MjdmNzQ3NGUyZjU3MWY3ODIxNGNmZGM3YTg2YmQyZjFmYmVkYzdmMDU1NTAzYWU3YTI5ZmFmNDNjZjZkNzlkNjNiYmY0ZTA5OTQxN2JlYjAzODI3OTY5OTIwN2FjODhlOWVhOWQ3NDI4ODFmMzAxMWMxNDNhOTdlZWEyYTFjZTc3YWEzZWE2NmY2NTBiOGY3ZjczNjMzMWEwNzU5NTI0MzViNGYwM2ZjYjIwOWIxNTEzMmQ0NWRiNzhiYTQ0YzQwMjhiZjIwNDNlZmNjZWQ4YjE2N2U5NjU5OyBQcmVzdGFTaG9wLTYyM2NkODcxNWNjOTA3NGRlNGQ0OWYwMTA4YTNlNzM0PWRlZjUwMjAwYjBmM2Y1ZDQ1MDAzYmQ0NWI1OGQ1NDFmMzYyN2IwZDc3YjIyYjg5N2Y1YjQ4YTdkOWY5YWEzMjQ1ZWI5M2IzNzYxNzEwMjdiZGVlM2M2ZmI1MWU0NjY4OWFmNmVlZjNmMDI2YzkyYWIxNzY3MmZmZmZjMjBhMzlkOWNhNzk5YTM3ZWQ5ZjQyMGMxOTFmZDk2M2MwNzViMjAzYTI5ZWNhZDVmZDFmYjdjYjFlMTM0MjA1ZDBiZTNjYjM1OWY1ZmZmZDU2M2NlNDAxMzVhODYxMWY5N2U5YTdiMGJiYzE1NDZjOWNiNzI5OTVkZmY2MzVhNTAxYWZlYTVmMDE3ZGIxN2IwOTg1ZmExZjg3YzhiMmViYzhmMThlODJmY2YwYmUzMDJhZTc5YTAwYzM4YzkyYzEzZWE4MGZiZGU5Yzc3ZDI4OGJjODdjY2NiNzYyMzJmNzJlYzZkMGIxNWUyYzk3YmE5NjdmN2Q2YmIwOWU1OWVlYTA5Nzk0N2RlMTZhZGM2MWE2OGI2MTUyOGY4OWQyMzRkNjhkNzY4OTg4YzE2ODg5NmU4OWYyNTc5ZjA5ODVlZTA3MjRkMGI1MTQzZjQ1ZjEwYWRmOWI1YTc4NDI2MzJlZDEwN2IyZjFiYjc1ZDRkNWY1ZGUyMjNmYWZiNDRiYjQyZTUzMzRmZmViNzgzYmFmM2VkNWQ2NGIyMmFiODEyZjA1ZjQyNzFhMmM3Mzk5ZDU3ZmUyOTNlNDU5MjczN2NiYTA1NzlmNTc5Mzk3ZTYyZjNhZmIxZjUzMjljMTY1OTU4NGQ0ZWMwODkyYzk1ZjMwNWUwNmRhYjM0ZTc0MmE3NjNlM2Y2YmRkYjgxZjJlMjkzOTFhM2FmZTJhMmJjMjMzMzg3N2Y1MjNmZGQ3Y2E0OWNjOTgwMDA0MDE5ODM2ZDU4OyBfZ2E9R0ExLjEuOTk0MzM0NTc4LjE1MzEyODY3NjQ7IFBIUFNFU1NJRD00MzJxajNvczRvZzQ1Yjl0cmlhazJic3Z0cDsgYWRtaW5lcl92ZXJzaW9uPTQuNi4zCiAgICBbQ29ubmVjdGlvbl0gPT4ga2VlcC1hbGl2ZQogICAgW1VwZ3JhZGUtSW5zZWN1cmUtUmVxdWVzdHNdID0+IDEKICAgIFtDYWNoZS1Db250cm9sXSA9PiBtYXgtYWdlPTAKKQo=', full_data = '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', ip_address = 'MTI3LjAuMC4x', device_type = 'ZGVza3RvcA==', unix_timestamp = 'MTUzMjc1ODUxOQ==', date_string = 'MjguMDcuMjAxOA==', id_shop = 'MQ==', id_cart = 'MTE=', id_order = '', id_cust = 'NA==', amount = 'NDQuMTc=', id_lang = 'NA==', status = 'dW5rbm93', timestamp = 'MTUzMjc1ODUxOQ==',  checkstr = 'N2IyODdhYzkxZDlhMThjMzMyOTc2NGI5NGQ1MDUxNDM='
```

Thanks in advance